# Why is this code not good for unit testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Apparently this code is not good for unit testing, I'm wondering why? What does it mean that a code is "good" for unit testing?

```
 public class B 
  {
        public int Y { get ; }
        public int X { get ; }
        public B() 
        {
          X = 3;
          Y = 7;
        }

        public B(int x) 
        {
          X = x;
          Y = 2 * x;
        }
  }

 public class A 
 {
        public B MyB { get ; set ; }
        public A() {MyB = new B ();}

        bool M1( int a, int b) 
        {
           if (a > MyB.X) return false;
           if (b < MyB.Y) return false;
           return true;
        }

        public B M2(int x) { return new B(x);}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

My first impression is a missing dependency injection on A()

```
 public A() {MyB = new B ();}
```

Basically you cannot mock/inject B to a constructor, which means you are left with real B object creation/behavior that you cannot influence.

Does not influence testability, but M2 method does not make sense. Whenever you use it, it can be replaced by simple `'new B(x)'` (not even mentioning breaking the single-responsibility principle of class A)

Comment: But after creation of A, you can set a new value to `MyB`, for example: `A a = new A(); a.MyB = new B(7);`

Comment: Valid point @SomeBody - Technically you can, you can then influence B behavior while testing. 
In general this class has many drawbacks.  ie. Encapsulation.

Other thing that I would challenge: Why do we init it to new B() in a constructor? If we can supplement B via setter, why to do it all if it is used only in M1 method? We could do M1(int a, int b, B myB) and we do not need to have it as a class member.